# error:no matching fucntion for call to 'Square::Square(SquareColor&,Location*)'

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor, default

I'm trying to make a chess game in C++ and I have an error I can't resolve

where the error is:

```
for(auto file : all_E)
    {
        Square newSquare= new Square(currentColor, new Location(file,i));
        boardSquares[i][column]=newSquare;
    }
```

These are the `Square` and `Location` Classes

```
class Square {
    SquareColor squareColor;
    Location location;
    bool isOcuppied;

public:
    Square();
    Square(SquareColor sqCol, Location loc );
    void reset();
    bool isOccupied();
    void setOccupied(bool occupied);
    SquareColor getSqCol();
    Location getLoc();
    char* toString();
};

class Location {
    File file;
    int rankk;

public:
    Location();
    Location(File _file, int _rankk);
    File getFile();
    int getRank();
};
```

I read about this error, and I tried to add the the default constructor `Square()` and `Location()`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Your declared constructor takes the second argument by *value* (i.e. a `Location`) not a pointer to said same as your calling code is trying to invoke.

Comment: You should post a [mcve] and the error message in the question. However, it is already clear that you a trying to pass a `Location*` (pointer to `Location`) while the function takes a `Location`.

Comment: using less `new` helps in 99,99% of all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are constructing a pointer (`Location*`), not an object (`Location`), which is why the constructor does not match.

Remove the `new`:

```
Square newSquare = Square(currentColor, Location(file,i));
```